# switch contenteditable attr

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Why does the line `obj.attr(b, 'false').blur();` not work? What is wrong here?

```js
$('#btnren').on('click', function() {
  let obj = $('#cptitlea');
  let b = 'contenteditable';
  if (obj.attr(b, 'false')) {
    obj.attr(b, 'true').focus(); // this works
  } else {
    obj.attr(b, 'false').blur(); // doesn't work
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cptitlea'>323</div>
<br>
<button id='btnren'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Because when you click on button, div becomes blurred

Comment: @Mohammad, removing `blur`  - doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the *setter* of `attr()` in the `if` statement. This means your `if` is actually saying 'if (jQuery object exists)', which is always `true`.

To fix this, use the *getter* of `attr()` to retrieve the value and use it in the `if` statement. Note that you can simplify the logic by providing a function to `attr()` which returns the new value to be set, based on the current one. Try this:

```js
$('#btnren').on('click', function() {
  let $el = $('#cptitlea');
  let b = 'contenteditable';
  
  $el.attr(b, function(i, v) {
    return v === 'true' ? false : true;
  }).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cptitlea'>323</div>
<br>
<button id='btnren'>CLICK</button>
```